# How to extract residuals from sempls{semPLS} (or from densityplot{semPLS})?

Tags: r

I have partial least squares path models (a mixture of formative and reflective latent variables) run via function sempls in the semPLS package. I would like to check for spatial autocorrelation in the model residuals (generated by ordinary least squares regressions between latent variables), but must first figure out how to extract them.
   [link to data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxBbFLUdtzHkRHh0N05GM3FMMFk)

```
land2011g <- read.table("percover2011.csv", header=T, sep=',', row.names=1)
land2011<-land2011g[c(1:2,4:16),]
topaphids<-land2011[c('A.cracc','R.padi','A.nerii','T.trifolii','R.maidis',
'Tetr.sp.','Pemphigus.sp.')]
r1 <- land2011[c(1:3,128:131)]
r1.s <- as.data.frame(scale(r1, center=T, scale=T))
r2 <- land2011[c(11:13,132:135)]
r2.s <- as.data.frame(scale(r2, center=T, scale=T))
r3 <- land2011[c(21:23,136:139)]
r3.s <- as.data.frame(scale(r3, center=T, scale=T))
r4 <- land2011[c(31:33,140:143)]
r4.s <- as.data.frame(scale(r4, center=T, scale=T))
r5 <- land2011[c(41:43,144:147)]
r5.s <- as.data.frame(scale(r5, center=T, scale=T))
weediness<-land2011[c('largest.total.cover.m2')]
noncols<-land2011[c('total.noncols')]

ifrom <- c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","weed.cover","aphids","aphids")
ito<-c("aphids","aphids","aphids","aphids","aphids",'aphids',"prsv","wmv")
inner.mod<-data.frame(ifrom,ito)
inner.mat<-as.matrix(inner.mod)

ofrom<-c('r1.corn.wheat','r1.soy','r1a.pasture.hay.grass',
'r1a.urban','r1a.forest.shrub','r2.corn.wheat','r2.soy',
'r2a.pasture.hay.grass','r2a.urban','r2a.forest.shrub',     
'r3.corn.wheat','r3.soy','r3a.pasture.hay.grass','r3a.urban',
'r3a.forest.shrub','r4.corn.wheat','r4.soy','r4a.pasture.hay.grass',
'r4a.urban','r4a.forest.shrub', 'r5.corn.wheat','r5.soy',
'r5a.pasture.hay.grass','r5a.urban','r5a.forest.shrub',
'weed.cover','aphids','prsv','wmv')
oto<-c('r1','r1','r1','r1','r1','r2','r2','r2','r2','r2','r3','r3','r3',
'r3','r3','r4','r4','r4','r4','r4','r5','r5','r5','r5','r5',
'largest.total.cover.m2','total.noncols','arcsin.sqrt.PRSV',
'arcsin.sqrt.WMV')
outer.mod<-data.frame(ofrom,oto)
outer.mat<-as.matrix(outer.mod)

prsv<-land2011[c("arcsin.sqrt.PRSV")]
wmv<-land2011[c("arcsin.sqrt.WMV")]
subsets <- cbind(r1.s,r2.s,r3.s,r4.s,r5.s,weediness,topaphids,
noncols,prsv,wmv)

plspm11<-plsm(data=subsets, strucmod=inner.mat, measuremod=outer.mat)

pmodp11<-sempls(plspm11, data=subsets, method="pearson", scaled=TRUE, 
maxit=100, convCrit="square")
```

The residuals(pmodp11) function returns a "NULL" value.

The densityplot function in the semPLS package will plot the residuals for me so I assume they must be stored in the sempls object, but I am not sure how to access them.

```
densityplot(pmodp11, subsets, use=c("residuals"))
```

[density plot of sempls object pmodp11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aof9X.jpg)

I also found the following code related to residuals prediction in `semPLS`, but attempting to use it gives me this error:

> `Error in UseMethod("predict") :   no applicable method for 'predict'
>   applied to an object of class "sempls"`.

```
residuals.sempls <- function(object, what=c("LVs", "MVs"), scale=c("scaled", "original"), total=FALSE){
    what <- match.arg(what)
    scale <- match.arg(scale)
    model <- object$model
    data <- object$data
    # LVs
    if(what=="LVs"){
        res <- object$factor_scores - predict(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
    }
    # MVs
    else{
      if(scale=="scaled"){
        pdata <- predict(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
        res <- data - pdata
      }
      else{
        data <- rescale(data)
        pdata <- predict(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
        res <- data - pdata
      }
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: Can you make this into a reproducible example (so that I can reproduce your error)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?noredirect=1#comment63050894_5963269

Comment: Sure -- I added in a link to the data and the rest of my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the function predict.sempls (defined on [R-Forge_predict.sempls](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/semPLS/R/predict.R?view=markup&root=sempls)) is inserted into the residuals.sempls function, residuals.sempls now seems to work with a sempls object to return model residuals.

```
residuals.sempls <- function(object, what=c("LVs", "MVs"), scale=c("scaled", "original"), total=FALSE){
    what <- match.arg(what)
    scale <- match.arg(scale)
    model <- object$model
    data <- object$data
    # LVs
    if(what=="LVs"){
        res <- object$factor_scores - predict.sempls(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
    }
    # MVs
    else{
      if(scale=="scaled"){
        pdata <- predict.sempls(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
        res <- data - pdata
      }
      else{
        data <- rescale(data)
        pdata <- predict.sempls(object, what=what, scale=scale, total=total)
        res <- data - pdata
      }
    }
    return(res)
}
```